# Unity: Android touch on Gui texture

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

Using Unity 4.1.2,  using C# mono, Android Development.

Hi guys Ive created the following script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ButtonLeftMove : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
public float MoveSpeed = 10;
private float min = -20f;
private float max = 20f;

void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () 
{
    MoveSpeed = 50F;
    GameObject joeblob = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("playertag");

    if(Input.touches.Length > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Touched");
        joeblob.rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.left * MoveSpeed);
        //rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.right * MoveSpeed);
    }

    Vector3 clampVel = joeblob.rigidbody.velocity;
    clampVel.x = Mathf.Clamp(clampVel.x, min, max);

    joeblob.rigidbody.velocity = clampVel;
}
}
```

Works great, object moves when the screen is touched, however this is true for any part of the screen.

this script is attached to my GUI texture, i only want it to be true if the GUI texture is touched Not anywhere on the screen!

what extra code am I missing?

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A GUITexture, which is a GUIElement has a method named [HitTest](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUIElement.HitTest.html). You can use this to test if your touch location is within your GUITexture. This would be something like

```c#
if(guiTexture.HitTest(Input.touches[0].position))
{
    //I'm hit, I'M HIT!! GOING DOWN!!!
}
```

Of course you'll have to make sure there actually are touches, but you get the idea.

Comment: so if i do something like this if(Input.touches.Length > 0 && guiText.HitTest(Input.touches[0].position)) ??

Comment: there is no guitexture

Comment: guiTexture. Capitalization is important there. And there should be if you attached the script directly to the GameObject with the GUITexture.

Comment: ah nvm it works, my intelisense is bugged, forgot about that xD